# Optimizing performance on objective-c method for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance

I have such method and have a hard time optimizing it to run better. It takes roughly 1 sec with 100 units and 4 times to get between `NSLog(@"Debug2")` and `NSLog(@"Debug3")`. And 2 sec on iPhone. With more units it takes more. 250 units and 5 times it takes 1,7 sec on mac, and 3,2 sec on iphone.

I don't think the performance lies in cycle within a cycle. As 250 * 5 = 1250, should not be too much for a computer to handle fast.

Method idea:

Input: NSMutableArray times - containing times (2012-12-12, 2013-01-19) and etc 
       NSMutableArray objectArray - contains `LogUnit` objects.
Output: Array of computed views.

Main idea: a view for each time with objects from ObjectArray whose time is the same.

I have made it faster by showing a small proportion of objects (see `counted` in code and `_breakPlease`), yet it's still not fast enough.

```
- (NSMutableArray*) sortViews: (NSMutableArray *)times and:(NSMutableArray *)objectArray
{
    NSLog(@"debug2");
    NSMutableArray *views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:times.count];

    NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SortLog%i ",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"ObjectNumber"].intValue];

    NSString *comp = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:number];

    LogUnit *unit;

    int counted = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x != times.count; x++)
    {
        @autoreleasepool {

        UIView *foo = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];   
        foo.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        int f = 0;
        int h = 0;

        NSString *attributeName = @"realTime";
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", attributeName, [times objectAtIndex:x]];
        // Filter the objectArray by the time, so we don't have to run through all the objects in objectArray, and check if time is right.
        NSArray *filtered  = [objectArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        for(int i = 0; i != filtered.count; i++)
        {
                unit = [filtered objectAtIndex:i];

                // Filter units by user choice (comp). Like comp = Warnings or comp = Errors and etc.
                if([[unit status] isEqualToString:comp] || [comp isEqualToString:NULL] || comp == NULL)
                {
                     // testing if the unit is correct to use
                    if([unit getEvent] != NULL)
                    {
                    // below is some computation for frames, to get them to proper position
                        unit.view.frame = CGRectMake(unit.view.frame.origin.x, f * unit.view.frame.size.height + 30, unit.view.frame.size.width, unit.view.frame.size.height);
                        [foo addSubview:unit.view];
                        counted++;
                        f++;
                        h = unit.view.frame.size.height * f;
                    }
                }
        }

        UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
        myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        myLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
        myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:88 green:154 blue:251 alpha:1];
        myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        myLabel.text = [times objectAtIndex:x];
        // Just adding a label with "2012-12-30" or etc on top of the view.    
        [foo addSubview:myLabel];

        foo.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320, h + 30 );
        h = 0;
        [views addObject:foo];

        // counting added views for performance, if more than 30, return, and show only small portion of whole units, user has the option to show all the units if he wants to, but that takes a time to load..
        if(counted > 30 && filtered.count != counted)
        {
            if(_breakPlease == false)
            {
                _broken = true;
                break;
            }
        }
       }
    }
    NSLog(@"debug3");
    return views;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things for you to try.

First for profiling:

- Try the profiler in Instruments;
- If you have some grudge against profiler then try to get median times for each part of your code.

Now for optimization:

- Run away from creating objects that are all the same inside the loops. Try to create sample objects and then reuse them or copy them;

  - Create a sample `UIView` and archive it and unarchive it whenever you need a new view. Apply this also to the `UILabel`;
  - Although I never used it there's a way to create a `NSPredicate` and apply some values later. This way you can reuse the same `UIPredicate`;
  - Save the colors you need also in a variable instead of asking to `UIColor` as we don't know how `UIColor` handles it;
- Can you short-circuit your inner `for` loop i.e. you have a maximum number of correct units ?

Well, the profiler should be enough for you to understand where is your bottleneck but I've let you with some ideas also.

Don't forget to report here the results! :)

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer and help. Could you say which Instrument in profiler I should try, I'm kind of new to profiler? As for correct units, where is only a small possibility that unit will be NULL. I may not check this, but it doesn't increase performance very much.. As for other points i'll try them in a few minutes :)

Comment: The Time Profiler. http://cocoaforbreakfast.wordpress.com/2011/03/01/time-profiler-when-a-small-change-can-bring-huge-gains/

Comment: Yup, just found that LogUnit viewDidLoad method, takes a lot of strain on time.

Comment: Check the code you have there then. But I guess you won't be able to avoid that method to be called as you need to check the view frame.

Comment: I'v optimized code in viewDidLoad method of LogUnit, and it did helped me save a lot of time. Thank you for your answer it sure did help me find a solution !

Comment: Have you used any of my suggestions for creating sample objects? Can you give an estimate of much time you saved?

Comment: Not very much. About 0,1 sec, but each second counts :)

Comment: Still no idea on the kind of optimizations you applied. It would be great for my learning also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23699/discussion-between-datenshi-and-fabio-oliveira)